# requests: Splitting an array into multiple identically named params?

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm currently dealing with a slightly odd (I think) API endpoint. Here is an example URL:

```
https://platform.segmentapis.com/v1beta/workspaces/myworkspace/regulations?status=failed&regulation_types=Suppress_With_Delete&regulation_types=Suppress
```

The odd thing for me is that `regulation_types` appears twice in the params.

Does python requests support constructing this kind of URL through the `params` argument?

I would like to take in an array of `regulation_types` and create a URL that complies with what the endpoint expects. I could easily generate this URL in raw python but I'm just curious if a pure requests solution exists.

Comment: Can you please provide a snapshot of the data you are working with?

Comment: lets say i have `status='failed'` and `regulation_types=['Suppress_With_Delete','Suppress']` as local variables. The question is how to use built-in requests functionality to produce the above URL.